Trial balance comparing figures per year / period but no data for one fiscal year
I am writing a trial balance to compare the current and previous fiscal years with periods.
Issue:
Current year - there is no transactions so no data in the table for that fiscal year.
Previous year - there is a balance and data in the table.
When running the report, the parameter excludes the GL that doesn't have data for the current fiscal year but should return as a null for current year and have an amount for the previous year.
I believe the fiscal year parameter is the issue, but also that there is no data for 2023. Not sure how to address this.
Any guidance will be appreciated.
Details are below.
Data that returns on the report
This is what the data looks like and how the report returns the data when there is a fiscal year and period in the table. There is data for 2022 and 2023.



YEAR
PERIOD
GL
AMOUNT




2022
2
123
1000


2023
2
123
0



Report:



GL
AMOUNT 2023
AMOUNT 2022




123
0
1000



Data that does not return on the report
This is what the data looks like and how the report returns the data when there is a fiscal year and period in the table. There is data for 2022 but nothing for 2023. What the report should do is return the data for 2022 even if there is no data for 2023.



YEAR
PERIOD
GL
AMOUNT




2022
2
123
1000


no data
no data
no data
no data



Report:



GL
AMOUNT 2023
AMOUNT 2022










STORED PROC Script
Sample looks like this:
select 
YEAR_0, 
PERIOD_0,
ACC_0, 
(CASE 
WHEN @PER = '1' THEN ISNULL (SUM((X.DEB_1 - X.CDT_1)),0)
WHEN @PER = '2' THEN ISNULL (SUM((X.DEB_1 - X.CDT_1)+(X.DEB_2 - X.CDT_2)),0)
END ) AS 'CY PERIOD',
select YEAR_0, PERIOD_0,ACC_0, 
(CASE 
WHEN @PER = '1' THEN ISNULL (SUM((Y.DEB_1 - Y.CDT_1)),0)
WHEN @PER = '2' THEN ISNULL (SUM((Y.DEB_1 - Y.CDT_1)+(Y.DEB_2 - Y.CDT_2)),0)
END ) AS 'PY PERIOD'

FROM ACCOUNT A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (SELECT * FROM BALANCE K
        WHERE K.YEAR_0 = @YEAR AND K.FCY_0 = '' AND K.BPR_0 = '' AND K.CPY_0 = @CPY
        ) X ON A.COA_0 = X.CPY_0 AND A.ACC_0 = X.ACC_0
 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (SELECT * FROM BALANCE K
        WHERE K.YEAR_0= @YEAR_0-1 AND K.FCY_0 = '' AND K.BPR_0 = '' AND K.CPY_0 = @CPY
        ) Y ON A.COA_0 = Y.CPY_0 AND A.ACC_0 = Y.ACC_0
WHERE X.CPY_0 =  @CPY 
AND X.YEAR_0=  @YEAR_0

Because there is no data for 2023, not sure how to return 2022 data with a null value for 2023.

A calendar or talley table - loads of answers available with a little searching

I have a table that just holds a calendar, starting from the year the company started until about 100 years into the future, it holds a row for every day, with a year column, and columns that tell me it its a weekday or weekend, and other information. Now these questions are all very simple for me, I just select from the calender table and join from there. I recommend a similar solution for you

use PIVOT operator
